# Inserting an image into TexShop on Mac Os Mojave

Tags: graphics, mac, texshop, png

I've been trying to insert a `.png` image into my document on LaTeX for Mac. I have my image in the same folder as the LaTeX file and all other associated files.

However when calling on the image in `\includegraphics`, it's just coming up as an error. I've noticed that when I go onto the location of the png photo to get info, the address of the image is in a different format to the versions of Mac on the tutorials I've seen so far. This is the info I use to call on the image:

> ‎⁨Macintosh HD⁩ ▸ ⁨Users⁩ ▸ ⁨cian357⁩ ▸ ⁨Downloads⁩ ▸ ⁨Entrepreneurship⁩

The text I have is below. Everything afterwards works completely fine.

Please help thanks :).

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\linespread{1.5}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[margin = 2.54cm, left = 2.54cm, includefoot]{geometry}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{float}

\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhead{}
\fancyfoot{}
\fancyfoot[R]{ \thepage\ }
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0pt}

\begin{document}

\begin{titlepage}
    \begin{center}
    \line(1,0){300} \\
    [3mm]
    \huge{\bfseries An Interview with Blank} \\
    \line(1,0){200} \\
    \begin{figure}[H]
        \centering
        \includegraphics{/Users/cian357/Downloads/Entrepreneurship/CD.png⁩}**
\end{titlepage}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

You are doing a lot of things wrong here

1. `\huge` does not take any arguments
2. I'd probably use `\rule` not `\line`
3. `\end{center}` is missing
4. `\end{figure}` is missing (I'd remove it completely, not needed here)
5. If `CD.png` is in the same folder as the `.tex` file, then I'd just use

   ```
     \includegraphics{CD.png⁩}
   ```
6. I don't know what those stars are for.

The code would then be (I used a different image)

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\linespread{1.5}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[margin = 2.54cm, left = 2.54cm, includefoot]{geometry}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhead{}
\fancyfoot{}
\fancyfoot[R]{ \thepage\ }
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0pt}
\begin{document}
\begin{titlepage}
    \begin{center}
    \rule{300pt}{0.4pt} \\[3mm]
    {\huge\bfseries An Interview with Blank} \\
    \rule{200pt}{0.4pt} \\
    %\includegraphics{CD.png⁩}
    \includegraphics[width=5cm]{example-image}
  \end{center}
\end{titlepage}
\end{document}
```